# FieldError on ManyToMany after upgrading to Django 1.3

Tags: python, django, django-models

Just been updating to Django 1.3 and come across an odd error. I'm getting the following error from some code which works with version 1.2.7.

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'email_config_set' into field. Choices are: id, name, site, type
```

The odd thing being email_config_set is a related name for a ManyToMany field. I'm not sure why django is trying to resolve it into a field.

The error occurs deep inside django:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./core/driver.py", line 268, in run
    self.init_norm()
  File "./driver/emailevent/background.py", line 130, in init_norm
    self.load_config()
  File "./driver/emailevent/background.py", line 71, in load_config
    events = list(config.events.select_related())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 168, in select_related
    return self.get_query_set().select_related(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 497, in get_query_set
    return superclass.get_query_set(self).using(db)._next_is_sticky().filter(**(self.core_filters))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 550, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 568, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1194, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1069, in add_filter
    negate=negate, process_extras=process_extras)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1260, in setup_joins
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'email_config_set' into field. Choices are: id, name, site, type
```

Any pointers or tips would be welcome.

Comment: Interestingly, this issue only appears when "DEBUG = True"

Comment: Is this a repeatable error if you create a new virtualenv and new django install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case was due to dynamic models, and their creation order. More specifically, some models which were dynamically created after others, were not defined when the _meta caches were filled, and therefore lead to errors. Clearing the caches or changing the creation order resolves this problem.

See also https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/RJlV5_ribZk/P6tv4QlJN4EJ